# RegularExpression Validator with radautocompletebox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, validation, rad-controls

In my application I have RadAutocompleteBox as bellow

```
    <telerik:radautocompletebox allowcustomentry="True" 
runat="server" id="comboboxTags" emptymessage="" 
inputtype="Token" width="100%" filter="Contains" 
delimiter=", " dropdownposition="Automatic" 
textsettings-selectionmode="Multiple" 
minfilterlength="1" maxresultcount="10">
    </telerik:radautocompletebox>

    <asp:regularexpressionvalidator id="tagIsInvalid"controltovalidate="comboboxTags"display="Dynamic"
runat="server"errormessage="Invalid tags"
validationexpression="^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*[,\s]*(?: [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*[,])*\s*$" />
```

Problem is that for first word it validates properly. But from second word it starts giving error.

I checked regularexpression but it is perfect as I want.

I am not able to understand what is happening here & why it is giving validation error.

Answer (score 0):

use Custom Validators and perform regular expression validation on the client.